# Andengine LANDSCAPE_SENSOR

Tags: android, orientation, andengine

Hi i've an andengine application created with ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR:

```
@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    CAMERA_WIDTH = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    CAMERA_HEIGHT = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    camera = new ZoomCamera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
    engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsSound(true);
```

but nothing happend when i rotate the device i already tried to add

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="sensor"
```

like this

```
  <activity
            android:name=".activities.AquaActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

it seems to recognize the orientation on start with this, but the orientation doesn't change while running the app

have i to do something special to get it work?

Comment: I am also interested in this one.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the XML settings, nor you have to do anything special. I am using LANDSCAPE_SENSOR without the extra lines in manifest. There is also nothing obviously wrong with your code.

If your app normally works (i.e. scene shows correctly, everything moves etc), and other apps/games rotate the screen correctly, then the last thing that comes on my mind is that you might be using older version of Android SDK than GingerBread (API level 9), which is a requirement for the LANDSCAPE_SENSOR to work.

Comment: ok, i'm using the api level 10, thanks for the info, that i didn't forget anything.. i think i've to review my code maybe i've disabled the feature by overriding any function

Comment: I recommend creating a simple prototype that just renders a sprite and test the sensor there. Also I think it is recommended to build against the newest SDK: 

    `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />`

I am not sure whether setting the minSdkVersion influences the ability to use sensor too.